# Read a property of a node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

How can I read a property of a node in neo4j?
For example I have a node called 'mug' of the type 'crockery' and color 'brown' which I created as

```
create (mug:crockery{category:'mug', color:'brown'})
return mug
```

This will create a node.

Suppose this node was created programmatically through a script or service. How can I read the property 'color' of this node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably review the [developer manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/) and maybe review some tutorials online.

You would need to match to the node in question and then return its color property. If `category` is unique to a :crockery node, then it would be enough to look up the node by its category and then return its color, like so:

```
match (n:crocker)
where n.category = 'mug'
return n.color
```

Note that I used `n` rather than `mug` here. The `mug` variable you used in your create query, like all variables, is never saved to the database, and is only present as a reference to a node (or nodes) and only persists at most until the end of the query.

Comment: I had searched online but could not fine relevant information. Most information was about finding a node based on property. your answer helped and also guided me about some more queries that I can deduce from your answer. Thanks :)